# Getting "The second parameter of split is a string, not an array" when processing input data

Tags: arrays, string, perl, variables, split

I'm new to this (first post!) and have been searching for a similar question for a number of days but cannot for the life of me find something similar enough to help (or cannot recognise it if it is there). If I'm wrong to post this question, please direct me to the right place :)

::

So I've just started using Perl, and I need to take some input:

xxx00_xxxx_xxx00 and split the string into bits separated by the '_'. This I have done using arrays.

problem is now I want to assign the values from the arrays into variables so I can use them.

Here is my novice code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# take input
print "enter ID:\n";
my $input = <>;

#split input
my @values = split( '_', $input );

print "$values[0]\n";
print "$values[1]\n";
print "$values[2]\n";

#assign split components to variables
my $customer_ID = $values[0];
my $service_ID  = $values[1];
my $ipac_ID     = $values[2];

#print components
print "Customer ID: $customer_ID";
print "Service ID: $service_ID";
print "IPAC ID: $ipac_ID";

exit 0;
```

BTW I know I have errors on line 19 (I cant figure that out either...)

any help appreciated - thanks!

Comment: @mpapec How to store the split data from array[0] into a variable to use later on in the program

Comment: You've already assigned the data from your split operation to variables -- $customer_ID, $service_ID, etc.

Comment: @ialarmedalien yes I did, I thought it would not work but it did!

Comment: So is there actually a question here? It seems as though you've answered it already.

Comment: What error are you getting on line 19?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message `The second parameter of split is a string, not an array` is from the Padre IDE you are using, not from Perl. It is produced by Padre's "Beginner's Mode", which naïvely checks whether there is an `@` between the text `split` and the next semicolon, even across multiple lines, and if so then it assumes that you have made a mistake. Of course that approach doesn't allow for comments.

The only errors you have - if you can call them errors - are

- You leave the newline in place at the end of your input string, so it will look like `"xxx00_xxxx_xxx00\n"` and `split` will produce `"xxx00", "xxxx", "xxx00\n"`. A simple `chomp $input` will remove that newline
- You don't print a newline after each scalar value, so your output is all on one line and your session looks like this

  ```
  enter ID:
  xxx00_xxxx_xxx00
  xxx00
  xxxx
  xxx00
  Customer ID: xxx00Service ID: xxxxIPAC ID: xxx00
  ```

  And all you need to do there is *add* a newline on each `print` (like you did with your earlier `print` statements) like this

  ```
  print "Customer ID: $customer_ID\n";
  print "Service ID: $service_ID\n";
  print "IPAC ID: $ipac_ID\n";
  ```

A tidier version of your program with more obvious choices would look like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# take input
print 'Enter ID: ';
my $input = <>;
chomp $input;

# Split input
my @values = split /_/, $input;

print "$_\n" for @values;

# Assign split components to variables 
my ($customer_ID, $service_ID, $ipac_ID) = @values;

#print components 
print "Customer ID: $customer_ID\n";
print "Service ID:  $service_ID\n";
print "IPAC ID:     $ipac_ID\n";
```

Comment: Borodin changed `split '_'` into `split /_/` because of the first parameter of `split` is expected to be a regular expression, so you might as well make it look like one.

Answer (score 3):

You can clean up your code a bit like this:

```
print "enter ID: ";
chomp(my $input = <STDIN>);

my ($customer_ID, $service_ID, $ipac_ID) = split(/_/, $input);

print "Customer ID: $customer_ID ";
print "Service ID: $service_ID ";
print "IPAC ID: $ipac_ID\n";
```

---

```
Customer ID: xxx00 Service ID: xxxx IPAC ID: xxx00
```

Comment: may I ask what chomp does and why it is used in your code snippet?

Comment: @Unixmonkey That is incorrect -- `chomp` cuts a new line marker from the end of a string. It is actually set to remove `$/` (the input record separator), which is the new line marker by default. If you set `$/` to something else, `chomp` will remove that instead.

Answer (score 2):

You may prefer this:

```
my ($customer_ID, $service_ID, $ipac_ID) = split('_', $input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you taking input from the keyboard?

If yes, try replacing `$input=<>` with `$input=<STDIN>`.

By the way, what is the error you are receiving?

Comment: Line 19: The second parameter of split is a string, not an array